# How do I change change the text on a label to an input or raw_input from shell in python?

Tags: python, text, input, tkinter, label

I want to make a basic program using python that will use the raw_input() or input() to ask the person to input a string from the shell and not in the python application window. I have this code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

Gui = Tk()
Gui.geometry('450x450+200+200')
Gui.title = ('lol')

label = Label(text='my Label').pack()


def ask_text():
    new_text = input('Input text here:\n')
    change_text(new_text)

def change_text(new_text):
    Label2 = Label(text=new_text).pack()
    if new_text != 'stop_program':
        ask_text()

ask_text()
```

When I run this, the python application just keeps bouncing on the mac, and it does ask me to input but the app only opens after I put stop_program. I basically want it to open and then change the label instantly after I type what to put. How would I do this preferably using tkinter?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be working for me? What exactly is your issue? Is it that the app does not open up till you enter `stop_program` ?

Comment: yes, I want it to open, and then ask me to enter a string, and then it should display the string and then ask me again

Comment: You code is missing mainloop(), by the way. But if you use Tk, than user input would be better of if obtained Tk widgets, not from console.

Comment: I'm very new to this so where exactly would I put the mainloop() and what would I have inside it and when would I call it to get this to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified your code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *pargs, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *pargs, **kwargs)

        self.label_text = StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("my label")

        self.label = Label(self, textvariable = self.label_text)
        self.label.pack()

        self.after(1000, self.ask_text)

    def ask_text(self):

        while True:
            new_text = input('Input text here: \n')
            if new_text == 'stop_program':
                self.master.quit()
                break;

            self.label_text.set(new_text)
            self.label.update()


    def change_text(self, new_text):
        self.label["text"] = new_text
        if new_text != 'stop_program':
            self.ask_text()



Gui = Tk()
Gui.geometry('450x450+200+200')
Gui.title = ('lol')


my_window = MyWindow(Gui)
my_window.pack()

mainloop()
```

Sorry, for not providing explanation, as I canlt spend more time on it now. Just try the code. But note one thing: because you get user input from console, tkinter window will be blocked during this. It will update the label, but you want be able to close it, as tkinter want respond to any events as the python is stuck at console input. Probably some multithreading would be needed here. And as I wrote in the comment to the question, better would be to ask for user input from tkinter Entry widget, rather than from console.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot, but is it necessary to have the button?

Comment: is there something to say, if the window is opened then start asking in the console?

Comment: I changed the code. I used `self.after(1000, self.ask_text)`. this starts asking for the input 1 second after MyWindow is created. You cant do it immediately, as the program will not reach mainloop and nothing will work. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not a very good answer. Having a `while True` loop in a GUI isn't typically how GUIs are made. There already is one infinite loop running, you shouldn't have an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.